# Custom angularjs validator does not have up-to-date view

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

In angularjs 1.3.15 I have a custom validator which uses its attribute value:

```
sApp.directive('customValidator', [ '$q', function($q){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel', 
            link :  function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
                ctrl.$asyncValidators.customValidator= function(modelValue) 
                {                           
                 // I need the value of "attrs.customValidator"
                };
            }
        };
}]);
```

I use this validator in the following way:

```
<form ... ng-show="data">
    <input ... custom-validator='{{data}}'/>
</form>
```

`data` is some data being asynchronously loaded by a web-service. Unfortunately when the validator is called the attribute value is not available yet (despite `ng-show="data"`). So i call `scope.$apply()` inside the validator. This solves my problem but I get the error `"$digest already in progress"`.

Does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: Maybe try `ng-if="data"` instead of `ng-show="data"`. That won't solve the `$digest already in progress error` though. That error is happening because you're not correctly using the `scope.$apply()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user3632710 `ng-if="data"` did the job. My code looks now like this:

```
<form ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-if="data"> <!-- ng-if cannot by on same DOM as controller -->
        <input ... custom-validator='{{data}}'/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a synchronous formatter/parser will suffice. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L49Rq2cUEdN4X0eWU0ox?p=preview)

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('exactlyEquals', function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      var validator = function(value) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('exactlyEquals', value == attrs.exactlyEquals);
        return value;
      };

      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
    }
  };
});
```

And its usage:

```
<form name="theForm">
    <input type="text" exactly-equals="test2" ng-model="data.name" />
</form>
{{ theForm.$valid }}
```

Comment: I am not interested in checking equality. It has to be an asynchronous validator.